# Searching through history with up and down arrow in zsh

Tags: zsh

When I first switched to ZSH when I would use the up arrow key to move through history it would filter the history based on what I had already typed so if I type `mysql` and then up I would be stepping through recent commands that started with `mysql`.

This is no longer the case, now if I use up it just steps thought the most recent commands regardless of what I've already typed. How can I turn this back on?

My .zshrc is very small and I've already tried turning all my options off.

Here is what is in my .zshrc

```
plugins=(git command-not-found svn debian screen vi-mode)
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

bindkey -v
bindkey "^R" history-incremental-search-backward
export EDITOR="vim"

# history stuff
HISTFILE=~/.zsh-histfile
HISTSIZE=2000
```

Comment: "My .zshrc is very small" except that whole oh-my-zsh bit...

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You had `up-line-or-search` bound to your up-arrow. This should do what you want:

```
bindkey '^[[A' up-line-or-search
bindkey '^[[B' down-line-or-search
```

[Edit]:

The command above only uses the first word to search. The following will use the whole line. See `man zshcontrib`...

```
autoload -U up-line-or-beginning-search
autoload -U down-line-or-beginning-search
zle -N up-line-or-beginning-search
zle -N down-line-or-beginning-search
bindkey "^[[A" up-line-or-beginning-search # Up
bindkey "^[[B" down-line-or-beginning-search # Down
```

Answer (score 21):

I'd highly recommend using `"$terminfo[kcuu1]"` or `"$key[Up]"` rather than hard-coded stuff like `"^[[A"` which may or may not work on any particular system.

Check out `/etc/zsh/zshrc` for more keys. Here's what it looks like on my system. I think the `terminfo` keys are more likely to be defined.

`key=(
   BackSpace  "${terminfo[kbs]}"
    Home       "${terminfo[khome]}"
    End        "${terminfo[kend]}"
    Insert     "${terminfo[kich1]}"
    Delete     "${terminfo[kdch1]}"
    Up         "${terminfo[kcuu1]}"
    Down       "${terminfo[kcud1]}"
    Left       "${terminfo[kcub1]}"
    Right      "${terminfo[kcuf1]}"
    PageUp     "${terminfo[kpp]}"
    PageDown   "${terminfo[knp]}"
)`

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/405358/276872

Comment: +1 -- This is important, and was why the accepted answer above wasn't working for me. If other solutions aren't working, try this first!

Comment: I tried the "$key[Up]" first because it looked friendlier, but only the terminfo did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: The $terminfo and $key variants of up/down don't work for me (iterm 3.4.15, zsh 5.8.1, MacOS Monterey), whereas "^[[A" does work fine. terminfo does work for pageup/pagedown though